# Facing `org.hibernate.hql.PARSER` Error while fetching data from DB in Grails with executeQuery() method. Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm trying to fetch data based on dateTime but I'm facing Some Problem My Query works in MySql, But in Grails it is giving Following Error:

`2015-09-11 11:59:00,697    ERROR   org.hibernate.hql.PARSER:56 line 1:182: unexpected token: airDuration
2015-09-11 11:59:00,709 ERROR   grails.app.controllers.com.my.test.rest.ipg.ChannelController:200   Invalid device parameter request :    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: airDuration near line 1, column 182 [ from      com.my.test.ipgData.ChannelSchedule  where      channel = 77 and ((airDate between '2015-09-29 05:30:00' and '2015-09-29 20:30:00') or ((airDate + INTERVAL airDuration MINUTE) between '2015-09-29 05:30:00' and '2015-09-29 20:30:00'))  order by airDate asc ]; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: airDuration near line 1, column 182 [ from      com.my.test.ipgData.ChannelSchedule  where      channel = 77 and ((airDate between '2015-09-29 05:30:00' and '2015-09-29 20:30:00') or ((airDate + INTERVAL airDuration MINUTE) between '2015-09-29 05:30:00' and '2015-09-29 20:30:00'))  order by airDate asc ]`

---

### Following is My Code:

```
ArrayList<ChannelSchedule> channelSchedule;

Date currentDateAndTime = new Date();
String scheduleQuery =  " from " +
                        "     ChannelSchedule " +
                        " where " +
                        "     channel = 77 and ((airDate between '2015-09-29 05:30:00' and '2015-09-29 20:30:00') or ((airDate + INTERVAL airDuration MINUTE) between '2015-09-29 05:30:00' and '2015-09-29 20:30:00')) " +
                        " order by airDate asc " ;

channelSchedule = ChannelSchedule.executeQuery(scheduleQuery);
```

---

### ChannelSchedule Class:

```
class ChannelSchedule {

    Date airDate;
    String airTime;
    int airDuration;
}
```

Comment: HQL is not SQL. There is no such thing as INTERVAL in HQL. And you shouldn't pass dates as string literals either. Use parameters, and pass actual Date objects.

Comment: @JB Nizet : Is there any alternative to execute this query and get the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define derived property (The same as @Formula in java)

```
class ChannelSchedule {

    Date airDate;
    String airTime;
    int airDuration;
    static mapping = {
         endTime formula: 'airDate + INTERVAL airDuration MINUTE'
    }
}
```

and use the `endTime` in your query

See more [here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#5.5.2.11%20Derived%20Properties)

Comment: but here also we are using `INTERVAL` and which is not supported by HQL, then how it'll work?

Comment: The formula uses SQL representation

Answer (score 0):

If you change your logic slightly you won't have to rely on SQL interval. You definitely should use real dates instead of strings

```
ArrayList<ChannelSchedule> channelSchedule;

Date start
Date end = //Wherever this comes from
use( TimeCategory ) {
    start = /* Wherever the start comes from */ - 5.minutes
}


String scheduleQuery =  " from " +
                        "     ChannelSchedule " +
                        " where " +
                        "     channel = 77 and airDate between :start and :end " +
                        " order by airDate asc " ;

channelSchedule = ChannelSchedule.executeQuery(scheduleQuery, [start: start, end: end]);
```

Comment: no actually this is not what I want.. I want all those channel having startTime > currentTime && endTime > currentTime 

but I'm not saving endTime in DB instead I'm storing just the StartTime & Duration in miuntes (i.e. EndTime = StartTime + Interval duratatoin Minutes)